# Powershell script to call exe with 2 arguments

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have to create a script which basically calls exe with 2 arguments (DLL and XML).

sample code :

```
$app = 'C:\Test.exe'
$arg1 = 'C:\Test.dll'
$arg2 = 'C:\Test.xml'

&$app $arg1 $arg
```

But I get error even when I tried to execute one line on powershell.

Can someone get me the correct script?

Comment: Do not mis-tag your questions. This is nothing to do with `C#`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Start-Process` with the switch `-ArgumentList`  You can also include `-wait` to get Powershell to wait for the process to exit before continuing with the script.

```
$options = "C:\test.dll C:\test.xml"
Start-Process -FilePath C:\exe.exe -ArgumentList $options
```